# Sony NWZ-E363 doesn't go in MTP-Mode

Tags: 12.04, sony, mtp

i want my mp3-Player to work as MTP.
Therefore I added a .config containing

```
options usb-storage quirks=054c:059b:i
```

file to /etc/modprobe.d. To prevent the device from beeing auto-mounted.
Furthermore I installed
mtp-tools
libmtp-runtime
libmtp9
libmtp-dev
libmtp-dbg
from the reps. Then I rebootet, plugged in the device.
It didn't get mounted but was displayed with lsusb, so I tried mtp-detect:

```
$mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.3

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
```

(same with sudo)

So I copied the the 69-libmtp.rules from the latest libmtp-Package on sourceforge to /etc/udev/rules.d and added the lines

```
# Sony NWZ-E363
ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", ATTR{idProduct}=="059b", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k",
ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

After that I rebootet again and I tried mtp-detect again. But without any success.